# How do you configure Django for simple development and deployment?

Tags: python, django

I tend to use [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) when doing [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_(web_framework))
development, but on a live server something more robust is
often needed ([MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)/[PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), for example).
Invariably, there are other changes to make to the Django
settings as well: different logging locations / intensities,
media paths, etc.

How do you manage all these changes to make deployment a
simple, automated process?

Comment: I don't do anything as fancy as anyone else apparently :).  I just take advantage of the ORM that django supplies.

Comment: The question was on how to automate the changing of settings to switch between environments :-)

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings

Comment: You can have a look at this package: [django-split-settings](https://github.com/sobolevn/django-split-settings)

Answer (score 86):

**Update:** [django-configurations](http://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) has been released which is probably a better option for most people than doing it manually.

If you would prefer to do things manually, my earlier answer still applies:

I have multiple settings files.

- `settings_local.py` - host-specific configuration, such as database name, file paths, etc.
- `settings_development.py` - configuration used for development, e.g. `DEBUG = True`.
- `settings_production.py` - configuration used for production, e.g. `SERVER_EMAIL`.

I tie these all together with a `settings.py` file that firstly imports `settings_local.py`, and then one of the other two.  It decides which to load by two settings inside `settings_local.py` - `DEVELOPMENT_HOSTS` and `PRODUCTION_HOSTS`.  `settings.py` calls `platform.node()` to find the hostname of the machine it is running on, and then looks for that hostname in the lists, and loads the second settings file depending on which list it finds the hostname in.

That way, the only thing you really need to worry about is keeping the `settings_local.py` file up to date with the host-specific configuration, and everything else is handled automatically.

Check out an example [here](http://github.com/JimDabell/lojban-website/tree/master/lojban).

Comment: what if staging (development) and production are on the same machine? platform.node() returns the same then.

Comment: Example link is down.

Comment: Great idea to determine the settiings based on host lists! My one nitpick is the nomenclature (settings_local.py is always imported first so any settings that aren't overridden, will still in fact be active in production, making the suffix `_local` rather confusing)  and the fact that you aren't using modules (settings/base.py, settings/local.py, settings/production.py).  It would also be wise to keep this in a separate repository... better yet, a secure service that serves this information from a canonical source (probably overkill for most)... so that new host doesn't require a new release.

Comment: Even better, if you're using machine management software, instead of checking the host list in the `.py` file, and thus giving every host access to information about the configuration of every other host, you could template the manage.py to use the appropriate settings file in your deployment configurations.

Answer (score 26):

Personally, I use a single settings.py for the project, I just have it look up the hostname it's on (my development machines have hostnames that start with "gabriel" so I just have this:

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname().startswith('gabriel'):
    LIVEHOST = False
else: 
    LIVEHOST = True
```

then in other parts I have things like:

```
if LIVEHOST:
    DEBUG = False
    PREPEND_WWW = True
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://static1.grsites.com/'
else:
    DEBUG = True
    PREPEND_WWW = False
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'
```

and so on. A little bit less readable, but it works fine and saves having to juggle multiple settings files.

Comment: I like this idea, but it won't allow me to differentiate between different Django instances running on the same host.  This would happen, for example, if you had different instances running for different subdomains on the same host.

Answer (score 25):

At the end of settings.py I have the following:

```
try:
    from settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This way if I want to override default settings I need to just put settings_local.py right next to settings.py.

Comment: This is slightly dangerous because if a typo in `settings_local` results in an `ImportError`, this `except` will swallow it silently.

Comment: You could check the message `No module named...` vs `cannot import name...`, but it's brittle.  Or, put your imports in settings_local.py in try blocks and raise a more specific exception: `MisconfiguredSettings` or something to that effect.

Comment: It latest version of Python you can use `except ModuleNotFoundError`

Answer (score 11):

I have two files. `settings_base.py` which contains common/default settings, and which is checked into source control. Each deployment has a separate `settings.py`, which executes `from settings_base import *` at the beginning and then overrides as needed.

Comment: I use this too.  It's superior to the inverse (dmishe's "from settings_local import *" at the end of settings.py) because it allows the local settings to access and modify the global ones if needed.

Comment: If `settings_local.py` does this `from settings import *`, it can override values in `settings.py`. (the `settings_local.py` file has to be imported at the end of `settings.py`).

Comment: That can be done anyways. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7047633/3124256 above.
@Seth That's a recipe for a circular import.

Answer (score 7):

The most simplistic way I found was:

1) use the default **settings.py** for local development and 2)
create a **production-settings.py** starting with:

```
import os
from settings import *
```

And then just override the settings that differ in production:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
           ....
    }
}
```

Comment: How does django know to load production-settings?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat related, for the issue of deploying Django itself with multiple databases, you may want to take a look at [Djangostack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack). You can download a completely free installer that allows you to install Apache, Python, Django, etc. As part of the installation process we allow you to select which database you want to use (MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL). We use the installers extensively when automating deployments internally (they can be run in unattended mode).

Comment: Alternatively I would like to recommend [Django Turnkey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.com/django) based on an Ubuntu *NIX stack with django preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the multiple settings files mentioned by Jim, I also tend to place two settings into my settings.py file at the top `BASE_DIR` and `BASE_URL` set to the path of the code and the URL to the base of the site, all other settings are modified to append themselves to these.

`BASE_DIR = "/home/sean/myapp/"`
e.g. `MEDIA_ROOT = "%smedia/" % BASEDIR`

So when moving the project I only have to edit these settings and not search the whole file.

I would also recommend looking at fabric and [Capistrano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capistrano) (Ruby tool, but it can be used to deploy Django applications) which facilitate automation of remote deployment.

Comment: Ansible is python and offers much more robust provisioning facilities than Fabric.  They pair nicely as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have my settings.py file in an external directory. That way, it doesn't get checked into source control, or over-written by a deploy. I put this in the settings.py file under my Django project, along with any default settings:

```
import sys
import os.path

def _load_settings(path):    
    print "Loading configuration from %s" % (path)
    if os.path.exists(path):
    settings = {}
    # execfile can't modify globals directly, so we will load them manually
    execfile(path, globals(), settings)
    for setting in settings:
        globals()[setting] = settings[setting]

_load_settings("/usr/local/conf/local_settings.py")
```

*Note: This is very dangerous if you can't trust local_settings.py.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use this configuration:

At the end of settings.py:

```
#settings.py
try:
    from locale_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And in locale_settings.py:

```
#locale_settings.py
class Settings(object):

    def __init__(self):
        import settings
        self.settings = settings

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.settings, name)

settings = Settings()

INSTALLED_APPS = settings.INSTALLED_APPS + (
    'gunicorn',)

# Delete duplicate settings maybe not needed, but I prefer to do it.
del settings
del Settings
```

Answer (score 1):

So many complicated answers!

Every settings.py file comes with :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

I use that directory to set the DEBUG variable like this (reaplace with the directoy where your dev code is):

```
DEBUG=False
if(BASE_DIR=="/path/to/my/dev/dir"):
    DEBUG = True
```

Then, every time the settings.py file is moved, DEBUG will be False and it's your production environment.

Every time you need different settings than the ones in your dev environment just use:

```
if(DEBUG):
    #Debug setting
else:
    #Release setting
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make things so much complicated? I come into Django from a PHP/Laravel background. I use `.env` and you can easily configure it.

Install this package

```
django-environ
```

Now, in the folder where you've `settings.py`, create a file `.env` (make sure to put this file in gitignore)

In the `.env` file, put the env variables like debug setting state, secret key, mail credentials etc
A snapshot of example `.env`

```
SECRET_KEY="django-insecure-zy%)s5$=aql=#ox54lzfjyyx!&uv1-q0kp^54p(^251&_df75i"

DB_NAME=bugfree
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=koushik
DB_PORT=5433
DB_HOST=localhost

APP_DEBUG=True # everything is string here
```

In the settings, make sure to instantiate it using this

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
```

Now you can import values from the `.env` file and put them wherever you want. Some examples in `settings.py`

```
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = bool(env('APP_DEBUG', False))
```

You can also put default value too like this

```
env('DB_NAME', 'default value here')
```

**TIP**
You can create another `.env.example` in the same folder where you've `.env` file and you can have a template of `.env` and you can commit the `.example` file. It helps the future dev to know easily what env variables are there.
`.env.example` would be something like this

```
SECRET_KEY=VALUE_HERE

DB_NAME=VALUE_HERE
DB_USER=VALUE_HERE
DB_PASSWORD=VALUE_HERE
DB_PORT=VALUE_HERE
DB_HOST=VALUE_HERE

EMAIL_HOST=VALUE_HERE
EMAIL_PORT=VALUE_HERE
EMAIL_HOST_USER=VALUE_HERE
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=VALUE_HERE
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=VALUE_HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the size of the site as to whether you need to step up from using SQLite, I've successfully used SQLite on several smaller live sites and it runs great.

Answer (score 0):

I use environment:

```
if os.environ.get('WEB_MODE', None) == 'production' :
   from settings_production import *
else :
   from settings_dev import *
```

I believe this is a much better approach, because eventually you need special settings for your test environment, and you can easily add it to this condition.

Comment: Please how do you get the settings_production and settings_dev values? What is your project architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post but I think if I add this useful `library` it will simplify things.

Use [django-configuration](https://github.com/jazzband/django-configurations)

#### Quickstart

```
pip install django-configurations
```

Then subclass the included configurations.Configuration class in your project's settings.py or any other module you're using to store the settings constants, e.g.:

```
# mysite/settings.py

from configurations import Configuration

class Dev(Configuration):
    DEBUG = True
```

Set the `DJANGO_CONFIGURATION` environment variable to the name of the class you just created, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`:

`export DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=Dev`

and the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to the module import path as usual, e.g. in bash:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`

*Alternatively* supply the `--configuration` option when using Django management commands along the lines of Django's default `--settings` command line option, e.g.:

`python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings --configuration=Dev`

To enable Django to use your configuration you now have to modify your **manage.py** or **wsgi.py** script to use django-configurations' versions of the appropriate starter functions, e.g. a typical **manage.py** using django-configurations would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Dev')

    from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Notice in line 10 we don't use the common tool `django.core.management.execute_from_command_line` but instead `configurations.management.execute_from_command_line`.

The same applies to your **wsgi.py** file, e.g.:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Dev')

from configurations.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here we don't use the default `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application` function but instead `configurations.wsgi.get_wsgi_application`.

That's it! You can now use your project with **manage.py** and your favorite WSGI enabled server.

Answer (score -2):

In fact you should probably consider having the same (or almost the same) configs for your development and production environment. Otherwise, situations like "Hey, it works on my machine" will happen from time to time.

So in order to automate your deployment and eliminate those WOMM issues, just use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).