# Distributing Django projects with unique SECRET_KEYs

Tags: django

I have a Django project that I'd like to distribute on a public repository like bitbucket or github.  I'd like it to be as easy to install as possible, so I'm including the full project, not just the pluggable apps.  This means that the `settings.py` file will be included as well.

How can I avoid the problem of `settings.SECRET_KEY` being the same for every installation?

Is the only *simple* solution to have the user manually modify `settings.py`?

Should I store the key in the default database and have `settings.py` initialize it if it doesn't exist?  That would solve the problem, but I'm wondering if there is already a standard way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you messing with the settings?  Everyone who downloads and installs a Django app can be trusted to fix the settings.

Comment: Change your secret key to something like "--- INSERT SECRET KEY HERE ---"

Comment: Everyone who deploys an SSH server can't be trusted to generate unique private keys, I don't see why it should be any different for Django projects.  The less configuration that must be done, the less chance there is of mistakes, especially with something like SECRET_KEY where you can't just type in something as simple as a directory path.

Comment: If you're going to store it in the DB, I'd recommend using a hash of the secret key, rather than the value.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'd go about it this way:

Have the secret key in a separate file "secret_key.py". This file does not exist for a pristine installation. In your settings.py include something like:

```
try:
    from .secret_key import SECRET_KEY
except ImportError:
    SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    generate_secret_key(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, 'secret_key.py'))
    from .secret_key import SECRET_KEY
```

The function `generate_secret_key(filename)` that you will write generates a file called `filename` (which, as we call it, will be `secret_key.py` in the same dir as `settings.py`) with the contents:

```
SECRET_KEY = '....random string....'
```

Where random string is the generated key based on a random number.

For key generation you can use Umang's suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630719/166761.

Comment: Your method is cleaner than my idea of storing the key in the database.  Thanks!

Comment: This method also requires that the user loading the `settings.py` module has write access to the directory it resides in.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but when you go to generate the file, you'll want to put it in a `try` block in case another booting worker process creates the file before you get to it, but after you've tested for its existence... that, or a lock. In the `except` block, you'll just import the file again.  In fact, it'd be better to just try to create it and on failure import, to avoid duplicate logic.

Answer (score 120):

To add to what [Carles Barrobés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664724/distributing-django-projects-with-unique-secret-keys/4674143#4674143) said, you can generate a new key using [the method that Django uses in `startproject`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9893fa12b735f3f47b35d4063d86dddf3145cb25/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py):

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
get_random_string(50, chars)
```

---

For Django 1.10 and above, the above code snippet is nicely wrapped up in a function.

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
get_random_secret_key()
```

[Link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/utils.py)

Comment: @MKaras Any string would work. My guess is that input character set is restricted in order to increase readability/accessibility. Therefore I would advise not to use `string.printable` as it contains some ‘tricky’ characters such as tabulation, new line, colon together with semicolon, space and others.

Comment: If you put this in your project, each separate Django process you have will have a different key. This means for instance that if you run multiple concurrent Django processes (or in separate servers), they will get different secret keys, so stuff signed from one instance won't work on another. Also, when your Django process is restarted, you will get a new secret key, causing similar problems.

Answer (score 39):

Open a Django shell with `python manage.py shell` and do the following to create a secure random secret key in Django 2.1:

```
>>> from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
>>> get_random_secret_key()
'[GENERATED KEY]'
>>>
```

Note: The `>>>` represents the shell prompt, and should not be typed.

Edit: Some answers here suggest automatically generating a file with a secret key in it from within the Django settings file itself. This is unsuitable for a production environment for a couple reasons. First of all, future deployments to new machines will create mismatching keys. Secondly, you'll need to take extra care to ensure there is no read access to that file from other programs or users. For these reasons **it is generally advisable and common practice to store secrets on production machines as environment variables**.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you can divide Django configuration into things that are app-specific and things that are server-specific.  This falls into the latter category.

There are a number of ways you can tackle the problem of server-specific configuration, it is discussed more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88259/how-do-you-configure-django-for-simple-development-and-deployment/88331).

For this particular instance, using the approach I outline in my answer to the other question, I'd put a placeholder in `settings_local.py.sample` for distribution, and during installation, I'd copy that over to `settings_local.py` and edit to suit.

Comment: I left this out of my original question to keep it less wordy, but I already have a settings_local.py file with MEDIA_ROOT, TEMPLATE_DIRS, SECRET_KEY, etc.  I'm looking for a way to automate generation of the key to prevent people installing the project from either forgetting to generate keys, or generating bad keys.  I think I will go with storing it in the database and having settings_local.py check for its existance.

Answer (score 3):

[Carles Barrobés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664724/distributing-django-projects-with-unique-secret-keys/4674143#4674143) made an excellent answer but it is incomplete, here is my version for python 3 with the missing function to work.

```py
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

def generate_secret_key (filepath):
    secret_file = open(filepath, "w")
    secret = "SECRET_KEY= " + "\""+ get_random_secret_key() + "\"" + "\n"
    secret_file.write(secret)
    secret_file.close()

try:
    from .secret_key import SECRET_KEY
except ModuleNotFoundError:

    SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    generate_secret_key(os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, 'secret_key.py'))
    from .secret_key import SECRET_KEY
```

Take notice that I changed the `ImportError` for `ModuleNotFoundError` and creates the python file `secret_key.py` to gather the SECRET_KEY like a variable instead to parse a txt file.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve the problem like this:

- Provide a dummy secret key like: `I_AM_A_DUMMY_KEY_CHANGE_ME`
- Create a manage command to generate a new one: `./manage.py gen_secret_key`
- In the documentation, STRONGLY advise users to run the command as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

In my code I have three levels of settings file inspired by Two Scoops of Django, so a middle one goes like this where BASE_PRIVATE_DIR is set up in the base template.  In my case this is from the django directory ../../mysite_private but somewhere ouside the normal files under the application git.:

```
from .base import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['staging.django.site'] 
#Allow local override which is per deployment instance.  There should probably then be
#  an instance git for version control of the production data
try:
    import sys
    private_path = BASE_PRIVATE_DIR.child('production')
    sys.path.append(private_path)
    from private_settings import *
except ImportError:
    print(" No production overide private_settings.py found.  This is probably an error  = {}".format(private_path))
    # If it doesnt' exist that is fine and just use system and environment defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new project using template, like `django-admin.py startproject --template=path_to_template project_name` just put `{{ secret_key }}` into your project template settings file (e.g. settings.py) like `SECRET_KEY = '{{ secret_key }}'` and Django will generate it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution I use [django-dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv), which is one of the dependencies of my project, as listed in `requirements.txt` like `django-dotenv==1.4.1`. The advantage of this approach is you have a different `.env` file for each environment where the application is installed.

Create the file `utils.py` in the same directory of `settings.py` with the following content:

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

def generate_secret_key(env_file_name):
    env_file = open(env_file_name, "w+")
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)'
    generated_secret_key = get_random_string(50, chars)
    env_file.write("SECRET_KEY = '{}'\n".format(generated_secret_key))
    env_file.close()
```

Then modify the `settings.py` file as follows:

```
import dotenv
from [project-folder-name] import utils
...
try:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
except KeyError:
    path_env = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
    utils.generate_secret_key(path_env)
    dotenv.read_dotenv(path_env)
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

For those who don't use `django-dotenv`, all you have to do it to add it as a dependency and change the `manage.py` to load it at startup:

```
import dotenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dotenv.read_dotenv()
```

Comment: This is actually pretty useful code. I'd only suggest to change the line in the utils.py to: `env_file = open(env_file_name, "a+")` as it might be holding some data already

Answer (score 1):

I found this block of code on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-generate-secret-key/) which almost works like Umang's answer.

Right in your project directory run

```py
python manage.py generate_secret_key [--replace] [secretkey.txt]
```

This will generate a new file `secretkey.txt` containing a random Django secret key. In your production settings file go and replace the secret key with the generated key.

Or in order to avoid hard coding the secret key. Add the following code snippet so that when you always run the program a new secret key will generate an updated key for you.

```py
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Use a separate file for the secret key
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'secretkey.txt')) as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

### OR

```py
# Use a separate file for the secret key
with open('/path/to/the/secretkey.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```