# Django App deployed on Heroku works despite wrong SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django, heroku, secret-key, django-deployment

In my Django project I have an `.env` file which holds my `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` environment variable:

```
export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=dummysecretkey123
```

I added a reference to the `.env` file in my `.gitignore` file before I initialized the repo, so the SECRET_KEY should not be visible in any repo tracked by git

In my `settings.py` I set my `SECRET_KEY` as follows:

```
SECRET_KEY = env.str("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")
```

For deployment on Heroku I added `SECRET_KEY` via Config Vars in the Heroku Dashboard - everything worked as expected.

Then out of curiosity, I changed the `SECRET_KEY` in Heroku to a wrong value to see its effect. To my surprise the app was still online and working. I restared all dynos, but nothing changed. Then  I checked the Heroku server's environment variables via `heroku run python manage.py shell` > `import os`   > `print(os.environ)` and could see the deliberately set wrong value for `SECRET_KEY`

What am I missing here? Isn't the purpose of the `SECRET_KEY` to protect my app, meaning that if it is not set properly, the app should not be working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effects of changing Django's SECRET\_KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170637/effects-of-changing-djangos-secret-key)

Comment: Thanks - so if I understand correctly: A wrong SECRET_KEY does not inhibit the app from running, because this is not its purpose in the first place, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of SECRET_KEY in django is described in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#secret-key).

It states:

> The secret key is used for:
>
> sessions,
>
> messages,
>
> PasswordResetView tokens,
>
> cryptographic signing.