# Create SECRET_KEY automatically in SETTINGS.PY via .ENV

Tags: python, django, security

In my study, I have generated my `SECRET_KEY` every time I start the project.
For this I use a variable in `.env` and the `eval` function in `settings.py`. These files look like this:

#### `.env`

```py
SECRET_KEY_VALUE_ENV = secrets.token_hex(100)
```

---

#### `settings.py`

```py
import secrets

SECRET_KEY = eval(os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY_VALUE_ENV'))
```

Is there any problem in generating the `SECRET_KEY` this way?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170637/effects-of-changing-djangos-secret-key).

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use dangerous functions like `eval()` on a value that you do not fully control.
You do not need the `eval()` anyway.

If another program or script manages to set the value of `SECRET_KEY_VALUE_ENV` in your environment, you'll have [Remote Code Execution](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/remote-code-evaluation-execution/) on your machine.

Scrape the `eval()` and use this instead:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY_VALUE_ENV')
```

The better way of generating the `SECRET_KEY` is to simply:

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key  
SECRET_KEY_VALUE_ENV = get_random_secret_key()
```

Comment: I changed this setting. I was taint this problem and appeared randomly [ Session data corrupted ]... Thanks for your comment.