# Django admin login SSL_do_handshake() failed

Tags: django, nginx, ssl

I get following in nginx-error log while logging in to admin page of django website

```
2022/01/28 17:04:50 [crit] 22184#22184: *263 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.232.184, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/28 17:08:12 [crit] 22184#22184: *277 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.239.221, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/28 17:08:30 [crit] 22184#22184: *288 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.232.251, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/28 17:10:09 [crit] 22184#22184: *302 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 45.56.98.215, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/28 17:28:03 [crit] 22184#22184: *344 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 165.227.140.0, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

One possible reason is I do not have the secret key I used while making the django project as I lost the .env file. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630719/9680018) to generate a secret key and to store in the .env file. Could this be the reason, or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with secret key. I briefly kept Debug=True in production to find out what was going wrong and I was getting the error

```
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC
```

And it was because of incompatibility of psycopg2 2.9> with Django 2.2.x. Found that from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68025007/9680018) and it fixed the issue.