# Organizing settings in Django

Tags: django

I am working on Django project that uses several dozen configuration variables specified in several "settings" files located in project's root directory:

```
--> myproject
------> app folders
------> ...
--- settings.py
--- settings_global.py
--- settings_production.py
--- settings_development.py
```

Variables from different settings_* files are then get imported in settings.py file based on certain run-time parameters (host name etc). It all works rather well, but sometimes it's still hard to locate certain variable, so I'd like re-organize settings variables and split them into several categories:

- project-specific variables
- django-specific variables
- installed-app specific variables (such as settings for django_compressor, etc)
- environment-specific variables (production/development)

Also I'd like to move all settings files but settings.py file to settings subdirectory:

```
--> myproject
------> app folders
------> ...
------> settings
---------- __init__.py
---------- common.py
---------- production.py
---------- development.py
---------- apps.py
---------- ...
--- settings.py
```

I've created settings subdirectory (as well as empty `__init__.py` file) and copied/renamed the settings files. Then I tried to import those variables in my setting.py file as following:

```
from settings.common import *
from settings.apps import *
```

However, I am getting the following error (even though ROOT_URLCONF exists in settings/common.py file):

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get this in apache error log (after restarting the process and visiting the project's page)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035733/how-to-modularize-django-settings-py  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583077/django-settings-py-separate-local-and-global-configuration  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there's a name collision between your settings.py module and the settings package, try renaming the package to something else