# Django static data, best practise filesystem

Tags: django, macos, deployment, ubuntu, static-files

I'm developing a site locally on my mac, and intend to deploy on Ubuntu. Usually I would put static content in /home/my_site/static/ (same for ./templates/) but on mac the /home/ directory is unwriteable. So if I want to keep my settings files consistant, is there anything wrong with putting my static files in /srv/static/ for example?

I've been looking at: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html (Filesystem standards) and 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modpython/#serving-media-files for a best practice solution, but I can't find one. Which suggests it doesn't necessarily matter where the files go?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you configure a different [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#static-root) for your [development and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88259/how-do-you-configure-django-for-simple-development-and-deployment/88331#88331) machine?

Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files) are really comprehensive in this regard.