# How did you setup your Django dev environment?

Tags: django, vagrant

I'm trying to setup a local Django dev environment using VMs enabled with [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) but I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it.

I did a `git clone` for Django files from production server and installed all the modules that the production server has on my local VM. I wanted to avoid installing a database on my local VM but ran into some problems with the sessions. The local machine is using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN='localhost'` and the production is using `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN='.mydomain.com'` so that creates some confusion.

Not to mention that on the setting.py on my dev environment I had to change IPs to point to the public IP address of the database (thus poking a hole on the security)  while my production settings.py is using the local IPs so I ended up using different settings.py files.

I can continue experimenting with new methods but I really have to get going with the project and I'm pretty sure some people had this figured out already.

So how did you setup your Django dev environment?

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be definitively answerable. There's dozens of ways to setup a Django environment and most of it boils down to personal preference of individualized needs of the given application. If you want to get some ideas, Google is the place for that.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I appreciate your input.

Comment: This question has been asked several times already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626326/how-to-manage-local-vs-production-settings-in-django and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88259/how-do-you-configure-django-for-simple-development-and-deployment

Answer (score 2):

I have a public repo on GitHub available here:

https://github.com/FlipperPA/djangovagrant

Instructions from the README.md:

Django / Python / MySQL

This is a Vagrant project for Django development.

This does not yet support berkshelf or librarian; all necessary repos are included in 'cookbooks'.

Prerequisites, all platforms:

Virtualbox https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
Vagrant http://downloads.vagrantup.com/

Pre-requisites, Windows only:

git-bash
ruby rvm

Fairly easy to get it running:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh djangovm
```

** (Note: You are now in the Virtualbox VM as superuser vagrant)

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

** (Note: PIP is a Python package manager)

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
sudo pip install django
```

Starting a Django project:

```
django-admin.py startproject django_project
cd django_project
python manage.py runserver [::]:8000
```

The VM is configured to use port forwarding. If everything went right, you should be able to access the running server through the browser on your computer running the virtual machine at this url:

```
http://localhost:8001/
```

New to Django? Next steps? I highly recommend: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/
For more advanced topics, check out Two Scoops of Django: http://twoscoopspress.org/

Comment: Considering the warning on the front page of djangobook, why are you recommending it?

Comment: Hi pydanny, I have updated the repo in my GitHub to point to Tango With Django, and to your excellent Two Scoops of Django book for more advanced topics. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @FlipperPA : Will it detect changes and reload `django server` if i make change in any `.py` files on my guest machine? I am trying this and it doesn't reload django server.

Comment: It should if you have your project in the shared folder. There's a much newer version available here: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant

Comment: Just confirmed that file status `last modified` get updated on host machine after i make a change to file on guest machine. Looks like some issue with `Django 1.5` autoreload

Answer (score 1):

there are a few django Apps that I've seen to manage this but I always prefer the following in my settings.py as the number of different configs are usually minimal

```
SITE_TYPE = environ.get( 'SITE_TYPE', 'DEV' )

if SITE_TYPE == 'LIVE':
    DEBUG = False
    DEFAULT_HOST = ''
else:
    DEBUG = True
    DEFAULT_HOST = '50.56.82.194'
    EMAIL_HOST = DEFAULT_HOST
```

Comment: Do you have a separate dev database that's similar to the production DB or you just point your Django dev code to the production DB? Thank you for putting some light on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [this repository](https://github.com/czerasz/vagrant-python-devbox).

You can modify it to support Django projects.

[`Vagrantfile`](https://github.com/czerasz/vagrant-python-devbox/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L62-l68) updates:

```
  config.vm.define "web1", primary: true do |web1_config|
    web1_config.ssh.forward_agent = true

    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
    web1_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.11.10"
    web1_config.vm.hostname = "web1.#{domain}"

    web1_config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioners/shell/python.setup.sh"
    web1_config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioners/shell/application.setup.sh"
  end
```

Then add a `provisioners/shell/application.setup.sh` file with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

local_user=vagrant

if [ ! -n "$(grep "^bitbucket.org " /home/$local_user/.ssh/known_hosts)" ]; then 
    ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null;
fi

if [[ ! -d "/home/$local_user/app" ]]; then
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:czerasz/sample-django-app.git /home/$local_user/app

    chown -R $local_user:$local_user /home/$local_user/app

    su - $local_user -c "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv sample-django-app-env && workon sample-django-app-env && pip install -r /home/$local_user/app/requirements.txt"
fi
```

Change the repository address (`git@bitbucket.org:czerasz/sample-django-app.git`) and make also sure that you have a `requirements.txt` in the root of your git repository. Run `vagrant up`.

Vagrant will start two machines:

- `web1` with your django project
- `db1` with a PoestgreSQL database

---

If you still have issues add the following to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
web1_config.ssh.private_key_path = [ '~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key', '~/.ssh/bitbucket' ]
```

And execute this command on your host (the machine where you run `vagrant`):

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

The `~/.ssh/bitbucket` is the ssh private key which you use for bitbucket. It can be `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or something different depending how you configured it.